# Cookie is not storing at root / but storing on request path

Tags: java, spring-boot, cookies

We are using Java spring boot. On the server side cookie path is set as / , as below
**set-cookie: SameSite=None; Max-Age=30; Expires=Mon, 22-Aug-2022 22:45:34 GMT; Path=/; Secure**.
But if we look at the path where the cookie stored in the chrome browser, it is same as request path.
**/api/xxx/v1/xxx/0f040edd-8130-4932-a062-ceedb68920b1/xxx**
.
We expect this to save in /, but why it is saving in the request path.
Please let us know.

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.